# Can't get URL paramaters

Tags: php, laravel, get, laravel-4

Laravel 4.1, PHP 5.4

My route looks like this:

```
Route::get('maps', function(){
    dd(Input::all());
});
```

The URL I load in the browser is this:

```
http://ag-aus.dev/maps?type=ctf
```

I'm expecting to get the value of "type" which is "ctf".

But the response I get is this:

```
array(0) {
}
```

I'm sure this used to work, but I have no idea why this is happening.

`var_dump($_GET);` also returns an empty array.

Comment: are you using query string in other places that work ?

Comment: @lagbox, no. The same/original query is used elsewhere but also does not work anymore.

Comment: perhaps your htaccess file is not passing the query string ?

Comment: Whoops. URL rewriting in nginx configs were not setup right. Fixed now. :) thanks.

Comment: Could you please close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx config was not setup to pass the queries to laravel.

**UPDATE**

I was missing the `?$query_string` parameter in my nginx site config file.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Source:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#pretty-urls

Comment: Would you mind explaining in more detail for future readers of this question?

Comment: @Noah Added an explanation. :)